# printf %f with only 2 numbers after the decimal point?

Tags: java

In my `printf`, I need to use `%f` but I'm not sure how to truncate to 2 decimal places:

Example:
getting

`3.14159`

to print as:

`3.14`

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use this:

```
printf ("%.2f", 3.14159);
```

Comment: It should be noted that this actually rounds the number, it does not just cut it off.

Answer (score 16):

You can use something like this:

```
printf("%.2f", number);
```

If you need to use the string for something other than printing out, use the `NumberFormat` class:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormatter("#.##");
String s = formatter.format(3.14159265); // Creates a string containing "3.14"
```

Answer (score 15):

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", number);
```

**BUT**, this will round the number to the nearest decimal point you have mentioned.(As in your case you will get 3.14 since rounding 3.14159 to 2 decimal points will be 3.14)

Since the function **printf** will round the numbers the answers for some other numbers may look like this,

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", 3.14136); -> 3.14
System.out.printf("%.2f", 3.14536); -> 3.15
System.out.printf("%.2f", 3.14836); -> 3.15
```

If you just need to **cutoff the decimal numbers** and limit it to a `k` decimal numbers without rounding,

lets say k = 2.

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", 3.14136 - 0.005); -> 3.14
System.out.printf("%.2f", 3.14536 - 0.005); -> 3.14
System.out.printf("%.2f", 3.14836 - 0.005); -> 3.14
```

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Answer (score 5):

Try:

`printf("%.2f", 3.14159);`

Reference:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 3):

as described in [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) class, you need to declare precision. `%.2f` in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
printf ("%.2f", 3.14159);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try
printf("%.2f", [double]);

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to learn it with printf because for many cases this will be sufficient for your needs and you won't need to create other objects.

```
double d = 3.14159;     
printf ("%.2f", d);
```

But if you need rounding please refer to this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/153785/2815227