# How to limit decimal places using printf in Java?

Tags: java, format

I'm trying to truncate to the third decimal point using printf in Java, but I keep getting to only the second decimal point. Here's the line of code where I was attempting this:

```
System.out.printf("The speed in ft/sec is %6.2f\n", time);
```

Comment: You're close, use `%6.3f`

see this also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197078/printf-f-with-only-2-decimal-points

Comment: You might just be looking for System.out.printf("The speed in ft/sec is %.3f\n", time);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.printf("The speed in ft/sec is %6.3f\n", time);
```

The above will *round* to three decimal places (not "truncate" them). The only difference is in the value after the dot.

Answer (score 7):

Try `%6.3f` instead. the format is

```
%(before).(after)(type)
    6         3    f

    6 -> 6 digits before the decimal
    3 -> 3 digits AFTER the decimal
```