# Is it possible to cast with precision in java without using the formatted printf?

Tags: java, casting

This line results in double value `3.33333333335`

`System.out.println("Average marks of " + name + " = " + (double)sum/3);`

Is it possible to set a width of precision?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [printf %f with only 2 numbers after the decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197078/printf-f-with-only-2-numbers-after-the-decimal-point)

Comment: it's not a cast. It's a print

Comment: No, the precision is fixed with double. That's why you need to format it if you want a different representation.

Comment: @Amongalen that's possible with printf method, but i was wondering if it is with print

Comment: It's not. That's one reason `printf` exists, to allow for formatted output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat` or `BigDecimal` as follows:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 10;
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.println(Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format((double) sum / 3)));

        // Another way
        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf((double) sum / 3)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

        // The better way using BigDecimal - thanks to @Andreas
        System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(sum).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3.33
3.33
3.33
```

Comment: Instead of potential precision loss when going through `double`, use `BigDecimal.valueOf(sum).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`. You can now exceed the precision of a `double`, e.g. with 25 decimals, resulting in `3.3333333333333333333333333`, where going through `double` would result in `3.3333333333333335000000000`.

Answer (score 0):

Print the result of [`String.format(String, Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) (which is the same as `printf` with an extra step), or use a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) (if you want a type with arbitrary precision).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to write function:

```
static double roundWithTwoDigits(double x) {
    return (double) Math.round(x * 100) / 100;
}
```

Now you can use it:

```
System.out.println("Average marks of " + name + " = " + roundWithTwoDigits((double) sum / 7));
```

Comment: I don't think it will work for really big numbers, will it?

Comment: Yep, for really big numbers one should use BigDecimals. It's more to answer the question as to how to get double-digit precise number without formatting. It's possible, but it's definitely limited and formatting should be used to format or BigDecimal should be used to control precision.