# How to round to 2.5 in Java?

Tags: java, android, rounding

So I am making a fitness app for android and now I am asking the user to input a number e.g. 72.5

I would take this number and take percentages of it and apply functions to this etc.

I need to make sure that the percentage I take of that number is rounded to 2.5. This is because in a UK gym you only have the following plates: 1.25x2=2.5 2.5x2=5 5+2.5=7.5 , 10, 15, 20, 25

What I mean is that it would be numbers like these: 40, 42.5, 45, 47.5, 50

How can I round a Number N to the nearest 2.5? I understand that math.Round() rounds to nearest whole but what about to a custom number like this?

Comment: Sorry if there is any unncessary info there but I thought it would be helpful to provide context

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449662/java-round-to-nearest-5 maybe thisone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(roundToNearest2Point5(12));
        System.out.println(roundToNearest2Point5(14));
        System.out.println(roundToNearest2Point5(13));
        System.out.println(roundToNearest2Point5(11));
    }

    static double roundToNearest2Point5(double n) {
        return Math.round(n * 0.4) / 0.4;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
12.5
15.0
12.5
10.0
```

**Explanation:**

It will be easier to understand with the following example:

```
double n = 20 / 3.0;
System.out.println(n);
System.out.println(Math.round(n));
System.out.println(Math.round(n * 100.0));
System.out.println(Math.round(n * 100.0) / 100.0);
```

**Output:**

```
6.666666666666667
7
667
6.67
```

As you can see here, rounding `20 / 3.0` returns `7` (which is the floor value after adding `0.5` to `20 / 3.0`. Check [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java) to understand the implementation). However, if you wanted to round it up to the nearest `1/100`th place (i.e. up to `2` decimal places), an easier way (but not so precise. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668820/is-it-possible-to-cast-with-precision-in-java-without-using-the-formatted-printf/60668971#60668971) for more precise way) would be to round `n * 100.0` (which would make it `667`) and then divide it by `100.0` which would give 6.67 (i.e. up to 2 decimal places). Note that `1 / (1 / 100.0) = 100.0`

Similarly, to round the number to the nearest `2.5`th place, you will need to do the same thing with `1 / 2.5 = 0.4` i.e. `Math.round(n * 0.4) / 0.4`.

To round a number to the nearest `100`th place, you will need to do the same thing with `1 / 100 = 0.01` i.e. `Math.round(n * 0.1) / 0.1`.

To round a number to the nearest `0.5`th place, you will need to do the same thing with `1 / 0.5 = 2.0` i.e. `Math.round(n * 2.0) / 2.0`.

I hope, it is clear.

Comment: Thanks so much! Totally works. I am wondering what your thought process was behind this?

Comment: You are most welcome. I've updated my answer to add the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply but you can also do 2.5*(Math.round(number/2.5))
Same way if you wanted to round in lbs to the nearest 5th its 5*(Math.round(number/5))